# Which is the probability that someone leaves before a new guest comes?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Guests arrive in the museum. The time between consecutive arrivals is exponential with parametr $2$. Each guest stays in the museum for exponential time with parameter $3$ and then he leaves, independent from the other guests. If the museum has now $4$ guests, which is the probability that someone leaves before a new guest comes?

Could you give me a hint for that? We have two exponential distributions. Do we have to combine them?

Comment: hint: if $X_1,\cdots,X_4$ are iid exponential random variables, then $\min\{X_1,\cdots,X_4\}$ is also an exponential rv

Comment: So do we have to calculate the parameter ? Is this the sum of parameters? @5201314

Comment: Correct, now think about how to compare the resulting distribution with the distribution of arrival times

Comment: So $4\cdot 3=12$ ? But how canwe relate that with the arrival tiimes of the next guests?@5201314

Comment: Think about the joint distribution and try using a double integral